# »solía« y »pretérito imperfecto«

Tags: tiempos-verbales

Dadas las expresiones:

> *Me **gustaba** algo*.
>   *Me **solía gustar** algo.*

¿Es equivalente la forma solía y el pretérito imperfecto?

Pareciera que sí, es como descomponer *gustaba = solía gustar* en donde el verbo *soler* solo posee su forma pretérito imperfecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo *soler*, en la práctica, no tiene más que el pretérito imperfecto y el presente. No se me ocurre ningún ejemplo de uso en otro tiempo verbal que no me suene extrañísimo.

En efecto, el significado de *soler* no es muy fuerte; solo aporta un matiz frente al uso directo del verbo que acompaña. Usando una ligera modificación sobre tus ejemplos:

> Me **gustaba** la comida de la cantina.
>
> Me **solía gustar** la comida de la cantina.

La diferencia está en que la segunda frase pone un cierto impedimento. Es decir: habitualmente me gustaba la comida que servían en la cantina, pero algunos días no era así.

Desde luego, puedes hacer lo mismo en presente:

> Me **gusta** la comida de la cantina.
>
> Me **suele gustar** la comida de la cantina.

No es normal usar el verbo *soler* en otros tiempos porque, por su significado, tiene un matiz imperfectivo: habla de acciones habituales o continuadas en el tiempo, por lo que el aspecto perfectivo no casa bien con él. El futuro podría funcionar cuando hacemos predicciones, pero la verdad es que me suena muy raro. Por ejemplo: si en una predicción meteorológica a largo plazo queremos decir que el próximo verano va a ser muy caluroso, podríamos decir: *Las temperaturas máximas durante el próximo verano solerán estar por encima de los 35°*. Pero yo preferiría usar otra expresión.

Comment: el futuro también me suena rarísimo, además casi como si debiese de ser irregular si lo usáramos en el futuro: *soldrán*

Comment: He visto su uso el futuro, y sí, es muy rarísimo.

Comment: He mirado el DRAE y actualmente dice que este verbo se usa principalmente en pretérito imperfecto de indicativo y en presente de indicativo y subjuntivo (*Llévate lo que se suela llevar en estos casos*). Pero creo que hasta hace poco se consideraba un verbo defectivo (es decir: los demás tiempos no existían). Yo, desde luego, no usaría ningún otro tiempo verbal con él.

Answer (score 0):

el [pretérito imperfecto](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos/preterito-imperfecto) significa principalmente *"describir Una Situación en el pasado".* pero también tiene un sentido *"una Acción Que se repitio en el pasado",* es decir, que describe un hábito/costumbre. `Soler` como verbo auxiliar sólo se aplica este sentido.